# How to take input from a column and change it to something else and count it

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

From this file https://1drv.ms/t/s!AjlMpzDMn2h7hWKyBGBxdhHXwjm8

I need to take column 3 which consists of numbers 1-6 and output those numbers to words like 1-sparkling, 2-fine without changing the file.

Also these have to be counted so I can output how many of each type there is with the corresponding name.

I tried many different kinds of `awk` codes and haven't been able to get it.
Currently I have

```
awk -F: '$3==1, ((counter++)) {print counter1}' wine.txt
```

which gives me no output at all.

Comment: post the input fragment and expected output

Comment: What is a input fragment? and the output should be like                                            sparkling=5                                                      fine=10                                fortified=9                                                                                                                     sweet=1         white=1                            red=7 the words sparkling, fine, fortified, sweet, red, white were all numbers and they got changed to those words and the number is how many times they show in the file.

Comment: *What is a input fragment?* - is that what you are calling *I have a file with 5 columns*. So, post that file

Comment: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AjlMpzDMn2h7hWKyBGBxdhHXwjm8

Comment: what's the meaning of that words in relation to the numbers? what's the logic? Let's say I've found 10 occurrences of number `2` and 15 occurrences of number `7`. What words should be specified and why?

Comment: Theres no correlation, also the numbers in the comment above were random numbers i provided. But in the 3rd column I was told to turn 2 into sparkling, 3 into fortified, 4 into sweet, 5 into white and 6 into red. So if theres 10 2's then it should output sparkling=10.

Comment: note, the number `1` does not occur in the 3rd column

Comment: that answer was perfect other then one thing. there is no 1 your right and there is no "fine" so in your code if you remove fine from the first line will it still work?

Comment: you can freely adjust the relation map to your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`awk`** solution:

Assuming the relation map:

*(sparkling=1 fine=2 fortified=3 sweet=4 white=5 red=6)*

---

```
awk -F':' 'BEGIN{ split("sparkling fine fortified sweet white red", words, " ") }
           $3 in words{ c[$3]++ }
           END{ for(i in words) print words[i]"="c[i] }' file
```

- `split("sparkling fine fortified sweet white red", words, " ")` - split the string containing crucial words into array `words` by separator `" "`(space) so that the array will be indexed with consecutive numbers having words as values (i.e. `words[1]="sparkling" words[2]="fine" ...`)
- `$3 in words{ c[$3]++ }` - check if the 3rd field value (containing a digit) occurs within array `words` indices, if so - count matches with `c[$3]++`

---

The output:

```
sparkling=
fine=15
fortified=28
sweet=10
white=23
red=24
```

Comment: Hi Roman, would you care to comment  the second line of the awk instruction: `$3 in words{ c[$3]++ }` by appending to yr answer (if possible) ?  I don't see that `$3` (taking values 1,2,...6 per the one-drive input file provided by OP) appears in the array `words` as defined in `BEGIN` line... and I am quite certain I am missing something. Tx.

Comment: @Cbhihe, see my explanation

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I have never seen documentation about referring to array indices in that manner. `$ man awk` does not document that ... I'll look it up in C... Tx again.