# How to output 1-30 while searching file for those numbers and how many times they appear

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I have a text file https://1drv.ms/t/s!AjlMpzDMn2h7hWKyBGBxdhHXwjm8

The last column is full of numbers from 1-30.

I need a code that will list each number from 1-30 but will also show how many times it appears in that column.

So it would look like

```
1=13
2=10
3=12 
.... up until 30.
```

currently i have a piece of code that I believe will work if i modify it correctly.

```
awk -F':' 'BEGIN{ split("sparkling fine fortified sweet white red", words, " ") }
       $3 in words{ c[$3]++ }
       END{ for(i in words) print words[i]"="c[i] }' file
```

Comment: derived from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406844/how-to-take-input-from-a-column-and-change-it-to-something-else-and-count-it/406855#406855

Comment: What has your `awk` code to do with the task you describe...?

Comment: It converts the 3rd column into those 6 words on the top and counts how many times they appear in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple approach (with the first lines from the file):

```
:> awk -F: '{ print $5; }' input | sort -n | uniq -c
 2 1
 5 2
 4 3
 5 4
 2 5

:> awk -F: '{ print $5; }' input | sort -n | uniq -c |
    while read count number; do echo "${number}=${count}"; done
1=2
2=5
3=4
4=5
5=2
```

**with awk only**

```
:> awk -F: '{a[$5]++}; END { for(i=1;i<31;i++) printf "%2d=%d\n",i,a[i]; }' input
 1=2
 2=5
 3=4
 4=5
 5=2
```

Comment: I used the second code in the first part, the one you used the while statement in. It worked good just for some reason it doesnt show the first number the 1-30. It only shows = and then how many numbers there are of that kind.

Comment: @ZachP That is very strange, the code works for me.

Comment: If i were to use the first code, is there a way i can print the words "in winery" between the two number?

Comment: @ZachP You can write whatever you want. You just have to put it in the output. What is the problem?

Comment: i took out the semicolon after the $5 and put "in winery" but the output is still missing the first number for me for some reason.

Comment: But when i use the example you gave that only uses awk it outputs the numbers 1-30 but doesn't count how many are in each.

Comment: @ZachP You have to change the argument to `echo`, not the `awk` code... In the `awk`-only solution you would need `printf "%2d in winery %d\n"`